# Detect target language in Haxe

Tags: java, javascript, c++, haxe

I'd like to detect the target language in Haxe so that I can change a function's behavior depending on which language Haxe has been compiled to.

Example in Haxe-like pseudocode:

```
class Test() {
static function printStuff(toPrint) {
    if (the target language is Java) {
        System.out.println(toPrint);
    } else if (the target language is C++) {
        cout << toPrint;
    } else if (the target language is JavaScript) {
        alert(toPrint);
    }

}
}
```

Is it currently possible to achieve this in Haxe?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [conditional compilation](http://haxe.org/ref/conditionals) along with [Haxe Magic](http://haxe.org/doc/advanced/magic) to achieve this.  For example:

```
#if java
    untyped __java__("java.lang.System.out.println(toPrint);");
#elseif js
    untyped __js__("alert(toPrint);");
#elseif ...
    ...
#end
```

Comment: This looks interesting. I've already begun learning the Haxe programming language.

Comment: It should be supported by any Haxe compiler backend.  Each backend gets to decide what macro to use for conditional compilation; it's not specified by the Haxe language itself.  For example, C++ probably uses `cpp`, but it could just as well use `cplusplus`.  The project providing a C++ backend for Haxe gets to choose.

Comment: So how would you translate my pseudocode example to real Haxe code?

Comment: Hmm... they way I did in my answer?

Comment: :) Note that I omitted the C++ section, since I am not sure what macro is defined when compiling to C++, as C++ is not an officially supported language as far as I can tell.  So... "this section left as an exercise for the reader."

Comment: C++ Is actually an officially supported target for quite some time now, and "cpp" is defined when you're targetting it.
By 2.10, cpp also supports untyped __cpp__() for directly writing cpp code

Comment: @Waneck Thanks for the info, I guess I didn't look hard enough for that macro.

Comment: Is it possible to detect the target language inside a method definition, as shown here?

    class Test {
        static function main() {
            trace("Hello World !");
            #if java
                trace("This is compiled to Java");
            #elseif js
                trace("This is compiled to Javascript");
        }
    }

Comment: I don't see why not.  I believe that the `#if` directives are evaluated by either the lexer or the preprocessor; the compiler should only see the block of code that matched.

Comment: I recently posted a question addressing conditional compilation inside a method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13165731/conditional-compilation-inside-a-method-in-haxe

Answer (score 5):

Or even just use trace.

```
class Test()
{
   static function main()
   {
       #if java
           var language = 'java';
        #elseif js
            var language = 'js';
        #elseif cs
            var language = 'csharp';
        #elseif php
            var language = 'PHP'
        #elseif (flash||flash8)
            var language = 'flash';
        #elseif cpp
            var language = 'c++';
        #elseif neko
            var language = 'neko';
        #elseif tamarin
            var language = 'tamarin';
        #end
        trace( language );
    }   
}
```

But it should be noted that the hxml for compiling this would need to have each target specified in theory it would be something generic like...

```
-java java
-main Test
--next
-js test.js
-main Test
--next
-cs cs
-main Test
--next
-php www
-main Test
--next
-swf test8.swf
-swf-version 8
-main Test
--next
-swf test.swf
-swf-version 9
-main Test
--next
-neko neko
--main Test
```

But in practice you will probably want to add other compiler flags and even use -cmd to actually run examples.

Getting started with a range of targets...

'http://haxe.org/doc/start/

conditional compilation

'http://haxe.org/ref/conditionals

compiler flags and options, although I may have missed a link.

'http://haxe.org/manual/tips_and_tricks
'http://haxe.org/doc/compiler

Then target magic

'http://haxe.org/doc/advanced/magic

For each target you can use generic haxe api along with target specific libraries named after the target

'http://haxe.org/api

My first reply on Stackoverflow so sorry if it's a bit verbose :) also the reason I can't post proper links (limited to two).

Answer (score 2):

Sorry but why did you show the untyped way?

You can have a fully typed and auto-completed code

```
class Test() {
    static function printStuff(toPrint) {
        #if java
            java.lang.System.out.println(toPrint);
        #elseif js
            js.Lib.alert(toPrint);
        #elseif cpp
            cpp.Lib.print(toPrint);
        #end
    }
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you simply use trace(toPrint), which works in every target language?