# Conditional compilation inside a method in Haxe

Tags: haxe

In the Haxe programming language, is it possible to detect the target language inside a method definition, as shown here?

```
class Test {
    static function main() {
        trace("Hello World !");
        #if java
            trace("This is compiled to Java");
        #elseif js
            trace("This is compiled to Javascript");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That should work, you only need to add #end after the last trace.

Comment: Should it be immediately after the statement `trace("This is compiled to Javascript");`, inside the main method?

Comment: That is correct ... conditional compilation doesn't understand the haxe syntax so #if/#else/#elseif/#end can be anywhere in the code and potentially they can break it (in some cases it can be handy).
For example this snippet will fail for every target but js: var a = #if js 1 #end;